Whitney Embedding Theorem - construction of a specific atlas
In Hirsch's book, in order to prove Whitney Embedding Theorem it is first proven that every compact manifold $M$ can be embedded in some Euclidean space. To this end, Hirsch claims that one can easily find a finite atlas $\{(U_k, \varphi_k)\}_{k=1}^{m}$, such that for each $k$ we have
$$\varphi_k(U_k) \supset B(0, 2)$$
and
$$M = \bigcup_{k=1}^{m}\text{Int}\,\varphi_k^{-1}(B(0, 1)),$$
where $B(0,r)$ is a closed ball  of radius $r$ centered at $0$. How can such an atlas be constructed? I suspect it could be done utilising paracompactness of $M$, but I am not sure how to proceed.

Why bother with paracompactness when one knows that $M$ is compact?
Start with an atlas indexed by $p \in M$, $\{(U_p,\psi_p)\}_{p \in M}$, such that $\phi_p(p)=0$ (one can "easily" find that atlas!)
For each $p$ choose $r_p > 0$ such that $B(0,r_p) \subset \psi_p(U_p)$.
Now replace $\psi_p$ by the function $\phi_p = \frac{2}{r_p} \psi_p$. It follows that $B(0,2) \subset \phi_p(U_p)$.
Next, notice that the open sets $\phi_p^{-1}(B(0,1))$ form an open cover of the compact manifold $M$ indexed by $p \in M$, because $p \in \phi_p^{-1}(B(0,1))$. So you can choose finitely many points $p_k$, $1 \le k \le m$ to obtain a finite subcover. Now set $\phi_k = \phi_{p_k}$ and $U_k = U_{p_k}$.
